# No Wireless connectivity after installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Windows 8

Tags: wireless, networking, 12.10, broadcom

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux.

I have installed the Ubuntu 12.10 version on Windows 8. After installation, there is no wireless connectivity. I have searched the forums and tried things that have worked for others. But, every way seems to be a dead-end to me.

I ran the command `lspci -nn | grep 0280` and here is the details I get.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
```

The command `sudo iwconfig` gives the below output.

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I downloaded the `bcmwl-kernel-source` from Ubuntu Software Center and installed, but there is no change.

I am at a loss, being new to the OS.

Any help from you will be much appreciated. Kindly let me know if I missed to provide any information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several drivers installed, the Linux kernel will pick the right one automatically. Regardless of the driver, though, your chip might need firmware to work. Find **firmware-b43-installer** from the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

The STA driver, provided by bcmwl-kernel-source is correct for your device.

> Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]

What is the result if you load the module? Are there warnings or errors?

```
    sudo modprobe wl
    dmesg | grep wl
```

Answer (score 0):

Install **synaptic** form the Ubuntu Software Center

In Synaptic select **bcmwl-kernel-source** and **bcmwl-sta-source**

Then **install** it.

I'm sorry you must have a connection internet try wired.